# Android Development Course-Unknown error

Tags: android

I have tried finding the problem here but I just can not, I am very new to android programming.
I am posting my whole project. I think the problem is somewhere ToDoListAdapter or onActivityResult() method, Everything is working except for when I click submit the new item doesn't show on the home screen. I have searched all the forums and tried different ways of inflating using LayoutInflater but I don't know what is wrong:

ToDoListAdapter.class:

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

public class ToDoListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// List of ToDoItems
private final List<ToDoItem> mItems = new ArrayList<ToDoItem>();

private final Context mContext;

private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

public ToDoListAdapter(Context context) {

    mContext = context;


}

// Add a ToDoItem to the adapter
// Notify observers that the data set has changed

public void add(ToDoItem item) {

    mItems.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

// Clears the list adapter of all items.

public void clear(){

    mItems.clear();
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

// Returns the number of ToDoItems

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return mItems.size();

}

// Retrieve the number of ToDoItems

@Override
public Object getItem(int pos) {

    return mItems.get(pos);

}

// Get the ID for the ToDoItem
// In this case it's just the position

@Override
public long getItemId(int pos) {

    return pos;

}

//Create a View to display the ToDoItem 
// at specified position in mItems

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


    //TODO - Get the current ToDoItem
    final ToDoItem toDoItem = (ToDoItem) getItem (position);

    //TODO - Inflate the View for this ToDoItem
    // from todo_item.xml.

      if(convertView == null){

      LayoutInflater inflater =(LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
           convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_todo, null);

    }

   // RelativeLayout itemLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);<<--No need to use it..       


    //TODO - Fill in specific ToDoItem data
    // Remember that the data that goes in this View
    // corresponds to the user interface elements defined 
    // in the layout file 

    //TODO - Display Title in TextView

    final TextView titleView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
    titleView.setText(toDoItem.getTitle());

    // TODO - Set up Status CheckBox

    final CheckBox statusView = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.statusCheckBox);
    statusView.setChecked(toDoItem.getStatus()==Status.DONE);


    statusView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            log("Entered onCheckedChanged()");

            // TODO - Set up and implement an OnCheckedChangeListener, which 
            // is called when the user toggles the status checkbox
            if (toDoItem.getStatus().equals(Status.DONE)) 
            { 
                  toDoItem.setStatus(Status.NOTDONE);  //Change it
            }
            else 
            {
                toDoItem.setStatus(Status.DONE); //Change it
            }



        }
    });

    //TODO - Display Priority in a TextView

    final TextView priorityView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.priorityView);
    priorityView.setText(toDoItem.getPriority().toString());



    // TODO - Display Time and Date. 
    // Hint - use ToDoItem.FORMAT.format(toDoItem.getDate()) to get date and time String

    final TextView dateView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
    dateView.setText(ToDoItem.FORMAT.format(toDoItem.getDate()));


    // Return the View you just created
    return convertView;

}



private void log(String msg) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, msg);
}

}
```

ToDoManagerActivity.class

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

public class ToDoManagerActivity extends ListActivity {

// Add a ToDoItem Request Code
private static final int ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST = 0;

private static final String FILE_NAME = "TodoManagerActivityData.txt";
private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

// IDs for menu items
private static final int MENU_DELETE = Menu.FIRST;
private static final int MENU_DUMP = Menu.FIRST + 1;

ToDoListAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create a new TodoListAdapter for this ListActivity's ListView
    mAdapter = new ToDoListAdapter(getApplicationContext());

    // Put divider between ToDoItems and FooterView
    getListView().setFooterDividersEnabled(true);

    //TODO - Inflate footerView for footer_view.xml file
    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(ToDoManagerActivity.this);
    TextView footerView = (TextView)inflator.inflate(R.layout.footer_view, null);




    //TODO - Add footerView to ListView
    getListView().addFooterView(footerView);


    footerView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            log("Entered footerView.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            //TODO - Attach Listener to FooterView. Implement onClick().
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AddToDoActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST);

        }
    });

    //TODO - Attach the adapter to this ListActivity's ListView

    getListView().setAdapter(mAdapter);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    log("Entered onActivityResult()");

    // TODO - Check result code and request code.
    // If user submitted a new ToDoItem
    // Create a new ToDoItem from the data Intent
    // and then add it to the adapter
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
        {
        ToDoItem toDo = new ToDoItem(data);
        mAdapter.add(toDo);
        }
        else
        {

        }   
        }
}

// Do not modify below here

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Load saved ToDoItems, if necessary

    if (mAdapter.getCount() == 0)
        loadItems();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // Save ToDoItems

    saveItems();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DELETE, Menu.NONE, "Delete all");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_DUMP, Menu.NONE, "Dump to log");
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case MENU_DELETE:
        mAdapter.clear();
        return true;
    case MENU_DUMP:
        dump();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

private void dump() {

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        String data = ((ToDoItem) mAdapter.getItem(i)).toLog();
        log("Item " + i + ": " + data.replace(ToDoItem.ITEM_SEP, ","));
    }

}

// Load stored ToDoItems
private void loadItems() {
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(FILE_NAME);
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));

        String title = null;
        String priority = null;
        String status = null;
        Date date = null;

        while (null != (title = reader.readLine())) {
            priority = reader.readLine();
            status = reader.readLine();
            date = ToDoItem.FORMAT.parse(reader.readLine());
            mAdapter.add(new ToDoItem(title, Priority.valueOf(priority),
                    Status.valueOf(status), date));
        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != reader) {
            try {
                reader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Save ToDoItems to file
private void saveItems() {
    PrintWriter writer = null;
    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILE_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
        writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(
                fos)));

        for (int idx = 0; idx < mAdapter.getCount(); idx++) {

            writer.println(mAdapter.getItem(idx));

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != writer) {
            writer.close();
        }
    }
}

private void log(String msg) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, msg);
}

}
```

AddToDoActivity.class:

```
package course.labs.todomanager;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Priority;
import course.labs.todomanager.ToDoItem.Status;

public class AddToDoActivity extends Activity {

// 7 days in milliseconds - 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
private static final int SEVEN_DAYS = 604800000;

private static final String TAG = "Lab-UserInterface";

private static String timeString;
private static String dateString;
private static TextView dateView;
private static TextView timeView;


private Date mDate;
private RadioGroup mPriorityRadioGroup;
private RadioGroup mStatusRadioGroup;
private EditText mTitleText;
private RadioButton mDefaultStatusButton;
private RadioButton mDefaultPriorityButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_todo);

    mTitleText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.title);
    mDefaultStatusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.statusNotDone);
    mDefaultPriorityButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.medPriority);
    mPriorityRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.priorityGroup);
    mStatusRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.statusGroup);
    dateView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
    timeView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);

    // Set the default date and time

    setDefaultDateTime();

    // OnClickListener for the Date button, calls showDatePickerDialog() to show
    // the Date dialog

    final Button datePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.date_picker_button);
    datePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePickerDialog();
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Time button, calls showTimePickerDialog() to show
    // the Time Dialog

    final Button timePickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.time_picker_button);
    timePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showTimePickerDialog();
        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Cancel Button, 

    final Button cancelButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelButton);
    cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log("Entered cancelButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            //TODO - Implement onClick(). 
            Intent intent = null;
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, intent);
            finish();

        }
    });

    //OnClickListener for the Reset Button

    final Button resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resetButton);
    resetButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log("Entered resetButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            //TODO - Reset data fields to default values
            mTitleText.setText("");
            mDefaultStatusButton.setChecked(true);
            mDefaultPriorityButton.setChecked(true);
            setDefaultDateTime();

        }
    });

    // OnClickListener for the Submit Button
    // Implement onClick().

    final Button submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            log("Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()");

            // Gather ToDoItem data  

            //TODO - Get Priority
            Priority priority = getPriority();

            //TODO -  Get Status
            Status status = getStatus();

            //TODO -  Title
            String titleString = mTitleText.getText().toString();

            // Date
            String fullDate = dateString + " " + timeString;

            // Package ToDoItem data into an Intent
            Intent dataIntent = new Intent();
            ToDoItem.packageIntent(dataIntent, titleString, priority, status, fullDate);

            //TODO - return data Intent and finish
            setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, dataIntent);
            finish();           

        }
    });
}

// Do not modify below here

// Use this method to set the default date and time

private void setDefaultDateTime() {

    // Default is current time + 7 days
    mDate = new Date();
    mDate = new Date(mDate.getTime() + SEVEN_DAYS);

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(mDate);

    setDateString(c.get(Calendar.YEAR), c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    dateView.setText(dateString);

    setTimeString(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), c.get(Calendar.MINUTE),
            c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    timeView.setText(timeString);
}

private static void setDateString(int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    // Increment monthOfYear for Calendar/Date -> Time Format setting
    monthOfYear++;
    String mon = "" + monthOfYear;
    String day = "" + dayOfMonth;

    if (monthOfYear < 10)
        mon = "0" + monthOfYear;
    if (dayOfMonth < 10)
        day = "0" + dayOfMonth;

    dateString = year + "-" + mon + "-" + day;
}

private static void setTimeString(int hourOfDay, int minute, int mili) {
    String hour = "" + hourOfDay;
    String min = "" + minute;

    if (hourOfDay < 10)
        hour = "0" + hourOfDay;
    if (minute < 10)
        min = "0" + minute;

    timeString = hour + ":" + min + ":00";
}

private Priority getPriority() {

    switch (mPriorityRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.lowPriority: {
        return Priority.LOW;
    }
    case R.id.highPriority: {
        return Priority.HIGH;
    }
    default: {
        return Priority.MED;
    }
    }
}

private Status getStatus() {

    switch (mStatusRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.statusDone: {
        return Status.DONE;
    }
    default: {
        return Status.NOTDONE;
    }
    }
}

// DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline date

public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        setDateString(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        dateView.setText(dateString);
    }

}

// DialogFragment used to pick a ToDoItem deadline time

public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Use the current time as the default values for the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return
        return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,
                true);
    }

    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
        setTimeString(hourOfDay, minute, 0);

        timeView.setText(timeString);
    }
}

private void showDatePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}

private void showTimePickerDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "timePicker");
}

private void log(String msg) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i(TAG, msg);
}

}
```

LogCat:

```
    03-01 11:18:16.638: I/Lab-UserInterface(2179): Entered footerView.OnClickListener.onClick()
03-01 11:18:16.828: D/dalvikvm(2179): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 305K, 12% free 4018K/4544K, paused 6ms, total 7ms
03-01 11:18:27.458: I/Lab-UserInterface(2179): Entered submitButton.OnClickListener.onClick()
03-01 11:18:28.038: I/Lab-UserInterface(2179): Entered onActivityResult()
03-01 11:18:28.048: I/Choreographer(2179): Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-01 11:18:28.408: D/AndroidRuntime(2179): Shutting down VM
03-01 11:18:28.418: W/dalvikvm(2179): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f29648)
03-01 11:18:28.548: D/dalvikvm(2179): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 71K, 7% free 4470K/4760K, paused 85ms, total 86ms
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at course.labs.todomanager.ToDoListAdapter.getView(ToDoListAdapter.java:114)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2177)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1840)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView.java:1321)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1633)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2012)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:349)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14289)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4562)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1976)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1730)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-01 11:18:28.548: E/AndroidRuntime(2179):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-01 11:18:33.448: I/Process(2179): Sending signal. PID: 2179 SIG: 9
```

Comment: So what is the issue you're actually having? Post some LogCat. There's too much code for people here to identify what you're having trouble with

Comment: @NickCardoso I have posted the logCat

Comment: Your logcat shows that you are running a test, not the app?!

Comment: @NickCardoso I have pasted the logCat in which I have tried to create a new to do item manually.

Comment: @zapl yes I have to pass those tests that I am running.

Comment: This code and exercise are from the Coursera Android Handheld systems course. I think this is against the Coursera Honor Code.

Comment: No it is not from the Android Handheld Systems course. Coursera Honor Code says I can not copy someone's code and I didn't. I implemented the assignment and I couldn't find what did I do wrong. So I asked for help on the forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
if (requestCode == 1) {
```

to

```
if (requestCode == ADD_TODO_ITEM_REQUEST) {
```

And you need to change adapter getview(), according to comments they say implement

todo_item.xml

```
//TODO - Inflate the View for this ToDoItem
// from todo_item.xml.

if(convertView == null){
    // rest of the code
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todo_item, null);

}
```

Comment: If i do this my application crashes. "Unfortunately UILabs has  stopped" when pressed submit.

Comment: I can not paste the logcat here, but the issue is that whenever i create a new to do item it doesn't show up on the main screen like it should.

Comment: run the app normally without running unit test. Then check the logcat.

Comment: I did it, and I have pasted the new log cat above. It is still the same when I press submit I get "UILabs has stopped working."